# C++ odd exception at overriden method call

Tags: c++, function, methods

I have a base class `A`, which will never be instantiated:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void visit(Visitor * v) { }
};
```

`Visitor` is also just a base class, it too will never be instantiated:

```
class Visitor {
public:
    virtual void visit(A * a) { }

    virtual void visit(B * b) { }
    virtual void visit(C * c) { }
    virtual void visit(D * d) { }
};
```

And here are the B, C and D classes:

```
class B : public A {
public:
    virtual void visit(Visitor * v) { v->visit(this); }
};

class C : public A {
public:
    virtual void visit(Visitor * v) { v->visit(this); }
};

class D : public A {
public:
    virtual void visit(Visitor * v) { v->visit(this); }
};
```

Now I inherit the Visitor:

```
class FooVisitor : public Visitor {
public:
    virtual void visit(A * a) { a->visit(this); }

    virtual void visit(B * b) { /*do something*/ }
    virtual void visit(C * c) { /*do something*/ }
    virtual void visit(D * d) { /*do something*/ }
};
```

And finally I make the main:

```
int main() {
    A * something = getSomethingLikeA(); // Returns a pointer to a B, C or D instance
    FooVisitor * v = new FooVisitor();
    v->visit(something);
    return 0;
}
```

And I get an unhandled exception at the visit method call. To be more concrete, here is a video of my situation: [LINK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XNGj-KGIOW0)

I have no idea what causes it, the debugger didn't really help me.

Edit:
Here is the source for the actual program: [download](https://www.mediafire.com/?d3bbvdxb41i7yi3) (8.31 KiB)

Comment: Pro tip: Use `struct` for asking questions, and save yourself tons of `public` noise. That focuses the problem and shortens the post.

Comment: You may like to learn about *pure virtual* member functions for your never-instantiated bases.

Comment: And this must be the absolute first that someone creates a **video** of their coding problems. That beats screenshots by a factor of infinity to one.

Comment: I just really can't find out what causes it! And yes, I know I should use pure virtual functions...

Comment: Please provide source code that I can compile and run to reproduce the error. Your code produces lots of compilation errors. After fixing those, I do not get any unhandled exceptions.

Comment: Parse parses an expression and returns one if it's found. I've checked it, the return is not a nullptr.

Comment: Added a download link to the source.

Comment: I still think that `parse` returns an invalid pointer (invalid pointer != null pointer)

Comment: I don't think so. I've created a method: void bar() {std::cout << "this works"; } for Exp class, and I can call it.

Comment: @PaulJ it does not prove anything, correct behavior is a subset of undefined behavior

Comment: you should investigate what happens in `parse` member function

Comment: Right. Do you have any guess what could cause an invalid pointer?

Comment: Got it! I'm amazingly stupid... I forgot to return a value. Thank you for pointing me there!

Comment: @PaulJ yes, some of your functions are missing `return` statement, where you should actually report an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at your code one can see that some of your `parseXYZ` member functions of `Parser` class are missing a `return` statement in all codepaths, which is a pathway to *undefined behavior* you are experiencing:

```
Exp * parseRelExp() {
    Exp * left = parseBinaryExp();
    if (lookahead->type == EQUALS || lookahead->type == NOT_EQUALS || lookahead->type == GREATER_THAN || lookahead->type == LESS_THAN || lookahead->type == GOE_THAN || lookahead->type == LOE_THAN) {
        TokenType op = lookahead->type;
        next();
        Exp * right = parseExp();
        if (right != nullptr) {
            return new RelExp(left, op, right);
        }
        else expect("Expression");
    }
    // what if we get here??
}
```

In most cases (though it's still *undefined*) the returned value is an arbitrary garbage from the stack, which, when interpreted as a pointer, may cause an application crash when dereferenced.

Answer (score 0):

The hierarchy you created and design you are using would lead to infinite recursive call in most of the cases. I believe that's the reason for exception.

```
    A * something = getSomethingLikeA();   
//Let's say you get object of type B.

    v->visit(something);
///would call FooVisitor's
    virtual void visit(A * a) { a->visit(this); }
//then class B's
    virtual void visit(Visitor * v) { v->visit(this); }
//and then again Foovisitor's
    virtual void visit(A * a) { a->visit(this); }  ////huh? I just called it back 
                                                   ////few stack frames.
```

After getting exhausted, it finds no other way than to throw exception straight at your face to get rid of these peculiarities...

Comment: `Visitor` has overloads for `B`, `C` and `D`